# library not found for -lcommonCrypto, Which is added in my project

Tags: ios

I have added `libCommonCrypto.dylib` library in my project from `Build Phase` but still my project display error below,

> ld: library not found for -lcommonCrypto
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is the screenshot of my `Build Phase` menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need that library to include directly, instead you can try
adding **`Security.framework`**

```
#import <Security/Security.h>
```